# How to distinguish first names from last names contained in array

Tags: python

I have an array called datos with names and surnames in random order

```
datos = ['Lucas Martinez', 'Gonzalez Carmen', 'Garcia Sofia', 'Cristian Ines Perez', 'Jorge Rodriguez']
```

As you can see, it can happen that there will be two names with one surname.

I also have an array with only names:

```
nombres = ['Sofia', 'Lucas', 'Cristian', 'Jorge', 'Ines', 'Carmen']
```

I want to find names and output with adjacent surname using the scheme:

"firstname lastname"

"firstname lastname"
like:

Lucas Martinez

Carmen Gonzalez

when there are two names to separate it into two separate data:

Cristian Perez

Ines Perez

I can find the name using this:

```
any(i.split()[0] in nombres for i in datos)

def verificacion(a, b):
    res = [i.split()[0] for i in a if i.split()[0] in b]
    return res

print(verificacion(datos, nombres))
```

but only for schema when name comes first

Comment: "here will be two names with one surname"  - there's no such

Comment: The think they mean `'Cristian Ines Perez'`, which has the surname `Perez` preceded by two names.

Comment: How would you determine if the name was first last rather than last first same for 3 part names? Do you have name library handy?

Comment: Yes, I mean 'Cristian Ines Perez' where 'Cristian' and  'Ines' are name and 'Perez' is surname

Answer (score 0):

Since names can be three "names" long, I would propose adding a preprocessing function. Afterwards, we can match all names to the `nombres` list and append them in the correct order as such:

```py
datos = ['Lucas Martinez', 'Gonzalez Carmen', 'Garcia Sofia', 'Cristian Ines Perez', 'Jorge Rodriguez']

nombres = ['Sofia', 'Lucas', 'Cristian', 'Jorge', 'Ines', 'Carmen']

def preprocess(datos):
    new_datos = []
    for person in datos:
        if len(person.split(' ')) > 2:    # get names which are 3 names long and split them
            s_name = person.split(' ')
            new_datos.append(f'{s_name[0]} {s_name[2]}')
            new_datos.append(f'{s_name[1]} {s_name[2]}')
        else:                             # default case
            new_datos.append(person)
    return new_datos

def verificacion(datos, nombres):
    ver_list = []
    datos = preprocess(datos)
    for person in datos:
        split_name = person.split(' ')
        if split_name[0] in nombres:        # add the name normally if it's in the correct order
            ver_list.append(person)
        elif split_name[1] in nombres:      # otherwise reverse the order
            ver_list.append(f'{split_name[1]} {split_name[0]}')
    return ver_list

print(verificacion(datos, nombres))
```

Probably a more succinct way of doing this but I'll leave that up to you. This should work if I understood the requirements correctly.